# C++ unordered_set insert accepts constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

Given these two classes

```
class User {
    string name;
    string eMail;
    pair<string, string> titleReading;
    vector<pair<string, string> > titlesRead;
}
class UserRecord {
    User* userPtr;
public:
    UserRecord(User* user);
    string getName() const;
    string getEMail() const;
    void setEMail(string eMail);
};
```

And this class which contains an unordered_set of UserRecords

```
struct userRecordHash
{
    int operator() (const UserRecord& ur) const
    {
        hash<string> h;
        return h(ur.getEMail());
    }

    bool operator() (const UserRecord& ur1, const UserRecord& ur2) const
    {
        return ur1.getEMail()==ur2.getEMail();
    }
};

typedef tr1::unordered_set<UserRecord, userRecordHash, userRecordHash> HashTabUserRecord;

class ReadingClub {
    vector<Book*> books;
    BST<BookCatalogItem> catalogItems;
    HashTabUserRecord userRecords;
    priority_queue<User> readerCandidates;
};
```

Why am I able to do unordered_set.insert(User*)? Does it call the UserRecord constructor?

Comment: Try to declare `UserRecord`'s constructor using the `explicit` keyword, and see what happens. More information on implicit conversions will be found in your C++ textbook.

Comment: When I changed it to explicit it no long worked, can you explain what is happening when explicit isn't declared?

Comment: Single argument constructions, unless explicitly told otherwise, can (and will) be used in *conversion construction* contexts. E.g. Something expecting a concrete `UserRecord` and being passed a `User*` will see there is a way to make a `UserRecord` from a single `User*`, and will craft a temporary to do so. That doesn't happen in *all* cases (ex: where a temporary isn't allowed), and, when explicitly disabled, happens in *none*.

Comment: Although I can quickly explain it, a more complete and detailed information will be found in your textbook. Is there something specific in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UserRecord::UserRecord(User*)` constructor is a *[converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)*, which means that it implicitly converts a `User*` value into a `UserRecord` object.

If you wish to prohibit this you can mark the constructor as [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) such that no automatic conversion is ever performed implicitly. You will always have to *explicitly* call the constructor you want to use.

This has nothing to with `std::unordered_set`. Observe:

```
struct I { I(int) {} };
struct E { explicit E(int) {} };
int main(){
  I a = 0; // okay
  E b = 0; // not okay
  E c(0); // okay
  E d = E(0); // okay
}
```

Note that with an explicit constructor, you could still `std::unordered_set::emplace` values (as opposed to `insert`). Or you could explicitly create the object you want to `insert`.